# Does Panasonic Inverter with Nanoe X technology harm electronics?

Tags: electrical

I may be looking to get a new split type air condition soon to replace my old one but it will be positioned near my computer. My concern is that according to this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sd3rwVnKd1s), this type of split type inverter features "Nanoe X technology" which releases "Hydroxl Radicals" which are enclosed in water to make them last longer. It takes about 30 minutes to fill a room with this.

I do work on my computer at my room, and if my AC is turned on I am not sure if it will leave moisture on my computer so much so that it would damage it. Would it be safe to work with sensitive electronics using this kind of split AC inverter?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with DIY, and asks advice on pseudoscientific flak.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Evaluating the features of a product offered by a top-tier HVAC manufacturer (Panasonic) that a DIY’er might install in their house is definitely on-topic and voting to close is abuse. The effectiveness of the hydroxyl is entirely irrelevant to the question of “does this device output elevated levels of water that might harm nearby electronics”. That question is perfectly answerable and on-topic.

Comment: @nobody, I have no problem with Panasonic -- indeed, I have a Panasonic microwave oven that use inverter technology to modulate the power, rather than switching on/off at low settings. The objection is to the **question**,conflating power management, "Hydroxl Radicals" (a possible translation gaffe in an ad,) and water damage. As it is written, there is no answer.

Comment: The question is not conflating power management with anything. “Inverter” is part of the model name of many air conditioners. It is not really relevant to the question of whether this particular AC emits a lot of humidity, but an unneeded detail hardly makes the question off-topic.

Comment: Note that the topic is home improvement, not necessarily DIY. Voting to reopen, though I'm not sure we have the answer since this is a unique and slightly weird feature and we may not have anyone who knows much about it.

Answer (score 2):

It's more like an air purifier/ionizer feature added onto the main cooling function of the mini-split. Sounds like it atomizes water into nano-sized droplets which they claim have many benefits in eliminating odors and pollutants. I doubt it would cause any water condensation issues other than increasing the humidity slightly.

Answer (score 2):

Websearch for "Panasonic nanoe X" finds a number of descriptions. It appears to be an attempt to get the effects claimed for ozone generators without actually producing ozone. "Nanoe" is their (pretty ugly, in my opinion) trademark for this process, the X appears to just be there for added woo-woo.

What I didn't find was any solid confirmation that this feature actually does any good at all. Or information about where it's getting the water to partly ionize.

BTW, according to the web, "An inverter heat pump is a heat pump that can operate at multiple speed settings. They use a piece of technology, sometimes called an inverter drive, or inverter compressor, to operate at variable speeds, as opposed to just turning off and on." I'm not sure whether that has anything at all to do with electrical inverters.

Answer (score 1):

"split type inverter features "Nanoe X technology" which releases "Hydroxl Radicals" which are enclosed in water to make them last longer."

What sort of pseudoscience is that??

- An inverter changes DC to AC electricity, and best **not** release anything into the air.
- Free [hydroxyl radicals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydroxyl_radical) don't last long, thank goodness; any quantity inhaled would destroy your lungs. It would be like inhaling lye!

If your question is about **moisture** released by the air conditioner, you'd need to *consult manufacturer's literature* to determine if there is a setting for **relative humidity (RH)** or dew point. As long as there is no water spraying out of the air conditioner (such a spray seems unlikely), and as long as the dew point is above the temperature of the equipment (i.e., not at [condensing humidity](https://www.tenney.com/applications/condensing-humidity) level), it should not damage equipment.

Comment: This question is not about a DC-to-AC power converter but an air conditioner. “Inverter” technology is a standard way of providing variable output in modern HVAC compressor systems. If you don’t know anything about the subject, just skip answering instead of posting irrelevant nonsense.

Comment: @nobody As I understand it, an "inverter heat pump" is so named because there is an inverter as one of the key pieces of how it works. Just like "inverter generators" and many other things. A key benefit is that it helps enable variable speed HVAC systems (not impossible before, but easier with an inverter).

Comment: Please reread my post again and watch the video, as what you have quoted from me is exactly what that video says.